# Cannot use context in class?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I'm currently trying to put in a color from my colors resources xml into my app using `ContextCompact.getColor()` but for some reason I cannot pass in a single version of context.

I'm using a class as a handler so I am not trying to pass in from an activity. In my activity I can use them, but in my class I cannot pass in `getActivityContext()` `this` etc. Nothing works. What do I do?

Also, I'm adding the color to a canvas so I cannot add the color in in an xml.

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Is what I'm currently forced to use. I want to replace it with a color from my xml. ( I'm trying to set the background of the canvas essentially )

full code of my class: (I'm making this app as a "note" app so that I can look back on it for future projects, hence all the comments)

```
public class GameHandling {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Resources resources;

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    private Ball ball;
    private Bat player;
    private Bat opponent;

    public GameHandling(int width, int height, SurfaceHolder holder, Resources resources){
        this.holder = holder;
        this.resources = resources;
        this.screenWidth = width;
        this.screenHeight = height;

        this.ball = new Ball(screenWidth, screenHeight, 400, 400);
        this.player = new Bat(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, Bat.Position.LEFT);
        this.opponent = new Bat(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, Bat.Position.RIGHT);
    }

    // setting the ball images to be drawn
    public void inIt(){

        Bitmap ballShadow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.grey_dot);
        Bitmap ballImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.red_dot);
        Bitmap batPlayer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.bat_player);
        Bitmap batOpponent = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.bat_opponent);

        ball.inIt(ballImage, ballShadow, 2, 0);
        player.inIt(batPlayer, batPlayer, 0, 0);
        opponent.inIt(batOpponent, batOpponent, 0, 0);
    }

    // calling Balls update method to update the ball
    public void update(long elapsed){
        ball.update(elapsed);
    }
    public void draw(){
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas(); // Making a canvas object to draw on - .lockcanvas locks canvas

        if(canvas != null) {
            // draw in area between locking and unlocking

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            ball.draw(canvas);
            player.draw(canvas);
            opponent.draw(canvas);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); //-unlockcanvasandposts unlocks the canvas
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `You can not pass`? Is it by design, or is it an error? If it is an error, post your code and the problem you are having

Comment: I meant calling it. So I cannot call getContext() etc

Comment: Pass the `Context` in the constructor then. Post the code from your controller class

Comment: added my class into my main post. Also just realized I was mislabeling it as a controller, my bad

Comment: `I cannot pass in getActivityContext()` there isn't much way around this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your constructor to this and use `ContextCompat.getColor(context,...` pattern.

Wherever you are creating this class (activity/fragment), pass the context calling either `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`

`new GameHandling( getActivity()/getApplicationContext(), ...)`

```
public GameHandling(Context context, int width, int height, SurfaceHolder holder, Resources resources){
    this.context = context;
    this.holder = holder;
    this.resources = resources;
    this.screenWidth = width;
    this.screenHeight = height;

    this.ball = new Ball(screenWidth, screenHeight, 400, 400);
    this.player = new Bat(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, Bat.Position.LEFT);
    this.opponent = new Bat(screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, Bat.Position.RIGHT);
}
```

Comment: You don't really have to pass resources if you are already passing context in the constructor. You can get the resources from the context using context.getResources().

Answer (score 0):

I kind of came up with a workaround, I created an image with my desirable color and then used that as the background of the app.

However it is still a workaround, so it doesn't solve my issue